# Can I process large number of text files faster than doing it sequentially?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm working with a dataset with thousands of text files, around ~700kb each. The filenames contain the input parameters which produced the data (column separated time, frequency, amplitude). I've created a dictionary with the filenames as keys, and the parameters as the values in a tuple (to be able to associate the file with the parameters).

Given the large number of files, I expect it to take some time due to I/O but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this? As of now I'm simply looping pandas over a dictionary of the filenames, and preforming my analysis within the loop.

```
for f in dict_of_filenames.items():
df = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(df) #then some analysis task
```

Similar questions on stack or elsewhere suggest concatenation, creating a larger dataframe using numpy or such, however I want to maintain the correspondence of each file's data with its filename/parameters, and I'm unsure of how I would link back if there were a larger dataframe.

Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: My first thought was to put all of your files into a ZIP archive and then iterate *inside the archive* which mean you're operating over pre-compressed data. This would be better for your IO (if that's the bottleneck).

Answer (score 0):

You should try parallelization of your code eg. with [`joblib.Parallel`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html), something like this:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def task(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
    ... some analysis ...
    return df # or the result of the analysis, e.g. mean value

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(task)(f) for f in dict_of_filenames.items())
```

The `results` list will contain whatever `task()` returned for each file.

(Note that I didn't test the code above, it's just so you have a starting point)